# Web server: How to validate a request-line

Tags: c, http, get, webserver

I am working on an assignment where I have to implement a simple web server in C. I have been given a distribution code that is missing parts. One of the missing parts requires that validate a request-line. Upon researching, I found out that:

```
Request-Line = Method SPACE Request-URI SPACE HTTP-Version CRLF
```

So far, my understanding is that I need to:

```
    size_t length = strrchr(line, '\n');

        if (strrchr(line, '\r') != length - 1)
        {
            error(400); // bad CRLF
        }

        line[length - 1] = 0;

        // now there isn't anymore CRLF
        length = strchr(line, ' ');
        line[length] = 0;

        char *method = line;
        char *request = line + length + 1;

         length = strchr(request, ' ');
         request[length] = 0;
         char * version = request + length + 1;


         char   *(methods[]) = {"GET", NULL};
         int    it = 0;

         while (strstr(method, methods[it]) == NULL)
         {
              ++it;
              if (methods[it] == NULL)
              {
                  error(405);
              }

              if (request[0] != '/' || strrchr(request, '.') == -1)
              {
                  error(501);
              }

              if (strchr(request, ',') != -1)
              {
                  error(400);
              }     

              if (strstr(version, "HTTP/1.1") == NULL || version[8] == '\0')

              {
                  error(505);
              }
          }
```

Is my approach (`pseudocode`) correct? Please shed some light on this matter.

Comment: An array or perhaps a struct.

Comment: Read this http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1

Comment: Paul, can you give a little more detail. I am kind of new to C.

Comment: There is no fixed list of method names; the only thing you can check is that they use only characters allowed in the method name definition.

Comment: Are they not referring to `GET`,`POST` etc..

Comment: Wehelie: yes, but the list of method names is not fixed. This is an HTTP extension point.

Comment: I just updated my `code` what do you think? Please let me know what you think?